# Databricks API 2.0 - Can't create KEYVAULT secrets scopes using SPN credentials

Tags: azure-devops, azure-active-directory, azure-keyvault, azure-databricks

I want to create a Secret Scope via the Databricks REST API 2.0.

**When I use SPN for az login I have next error** when run request /api/2.0/secrets/scopes/create

```
{"error_code":"CUSTOMER_UNAUTHORIZED","message":"Unable to grant read/list permission to Databricks service principal to KeyVault 'https://dtbrcks-kvxxx.vault.azure.net/': key not found: https://management.core.windows.net/"}%
```

**But when I use User login same code worked fine!**

SPN and User have same permissions on Databricks(Owner/Admin) and Keyvault (Owner)resources.

**What necessary for make this operation using SPN?**

For get access token I use commands

```
az login --service-principal

access_token=$(az account get-access-token \
                   --resource 2ff814a6-3304-4ab8-85cb-cd0e6f879c1d \
                   --query "accessToken" \
                   --output tsv)
```

And next code for create Secret Scope with Azure Keyvault:

```
curl -X POST \-H "Authorization: Bearer $access_token" \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
-d '{"scope":"keyvault-scope","scope_backend_type":"AZURE_KEYVAULT","backend_azure_keyvault":{"resource_id":"/subscriptions/$subid/resourceGroups/$rg/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/$kvname","dns_name":"$kv_url"}}' \
"$dtbrcks_url/api/2.0/secrets/scopes/create"
```

Answer (score -1):

If your service principal is the `Owner` of the databricks workspace, and meets any of the following conditions,

[image]

you  must provide the `X-Databricks-Azure-Workspace-Resource-Id` header and a management access token for the Azure Resource Management endpoint when you call the API.

To get the management access token, just change the `resource` to `https://management.core.windows.net`.

```
management_access_token=$(az account get-access-token \
                   --resource 'https://management.core.windows.net' \
                   --query "accessToken" \
                   --output tsv)
```

Then pass it in the request like this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/api/latest/aad/service-prin-aad-token#use-the-management-endpoint-access-token-to-access-the-databricks-rest-api).

```
curl -X POST \-H "Authorization: Bearer $access_token" \
-H 'X-Databricks-Azure-SP-Management-Token: <management-access-token>' \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
-d '{"scope":"keyvault-scope","scope_backend_type":"AZURE_KEYVAULT","backend_azure_keyvault":{"resource_id":"/subscriptions/$subid/resourceGroups/$rg/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/$kvname","dns_name":"$kv_url"}}' \
"$dtbrcks_url/api/2.0/secrets/scopes/create"
```

Or you can use [Non-admin user login](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/api/latest/aad/service-prin-aad-token#non-admin-user-login), prior to this login, the service principal must be added to the workspace either as part of the [admin user login](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/api/latest/aad/service-prin-aad-token#admin-user-login) or using the [Add service principal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/api/latest/scim/scim-sp#add-service-principal) endpoint, then you can [use the AAD token to call the API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/api/latest/aad/service-prin-aad-token#use-an-access-token-to-access-the-databricks-rest-api) directly.

Comment: It's doesn't work when I use X-Databricks-Azure-SP-Management-Token. Also SPN already registered as Databricks admin user and have Personal token. And when I try to use Personal token I got next interesting api response: `{"error_code":"INVALID_PARAMETER_VALUE","message":"Scope with Azure KeyVault must have userAADToken defined!"}`.  It mean I can use only userAADToken !!! - Why ?

Comment: When I use X-Databricks-Azure-SP-Management-Token it doesn't work with fault `{"error_code":"INTERNAL_ERROR","message":"Internal error happened while granting read/list permission to Databricks service principal to KeyVault: https://dtbrcks-kvxxx.vault.azure.net/"}`

Comment: @SergeyElchinskiy Did you use the `X-Databricks-Azure-SP-Management-Token` along with the AAD token?

Comment: Yes, I use Management-Token with AAD token from SPN and it failed. But If I use az login with AAD User credentials and run same commands - it's working!!!